# Symofiny2, Perfom Criteria on Entity Object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle

i am Working on Symfony Project. i am getting the list of Stores from Bundle. in the below controller action, i want to know from where the results are coming.

Check the Snippet "EducateToolsBundle:Stores" in below code.

```
myAction (){
    $stores = c2gr($this, 'EducateToolsBundle:Stores')->findBySelectOption(true); // Where can i Find/change the Data of stores.
    $userLocations = array();
    foreach ($stores as $store) {
        $userLocations[] = $store->getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `c2gr` is, so I'm going to assume it's a custom function that's getting your doctrine repository. Simmilar to this:

```
$repo = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('EducateToolsbundle:Stores');
$stores = $repo->findBySelectOption(true);
```

The results will be coming from what ever database you're project is using, whether it me MySQL, Postgres, MongoDB or something else.

If you want to change the stores, you can do that in code by calling a setter on the Store entity (you'll have to check your entity to see what setters actually exist):

```
foreach ($stores as $store) {
    // Assuming that a Store has a SetLocation method that takes a string
    $store->setLocation('Las Vegas');
}
```

If you just need to do a quick change to the data and don't want to write code, you will need access to the database.

**UPDATE** from comments

The `findBySelectOption` is how Doctrine does things like a `WHERE` clause in SQL. So calling `findBySelectOption(true)` will roughly translate to:

```
SELECT * FROM Stores WHERE SelectOption = true;
```

If you want to find stores who have LOCTYPE=9, then you can replace `findBySelectOption(true)` with:

```
findBy(['selectOption' => true, 'LOCTYPE' => 9])
```

Which will translate to:

```
SELECT * FROM Stores WHERE SelectOption = true AND LOCTYPE = 9;
```

NOTE: you will have to check your Stores entity, to find the correct casing of `SelectOption` and `LOCTYPE`, otherwise it may not work.
ie. Is the attribte on Stores called `LOCTYPE` or `loctype` or `LocType`?

**UPDATE 2**
If you want to find by not equal, for instance:

```
WHERE LOCTYPE != 9
```

Then you have to do a bit extra work with the query builder. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085946/doctrine-findby-does-not-equal).

Comment: is `$store->setLocation('Las Vegas');` work like Where Condition .?

Comment: No, it's changing the location of the store. (I don't know if you're stores actually have a `location` attribute, this is just an example of a setter.)

I thought you were asking how to edit the store once you have it. But are you asking how to us a where condition in doctrine? like `SELECT * FROM Stores WHERE Location = 'Las Vegas';` is SQL?

Comment: Doctrain is Fine, Can i get the list of results based on an attribute `TYPE=9` using my Code .?

Comment: as of now i am getting the all stores i want to get the only store those attribute LOCTYPE=9. i want to add this condition to my results, i am expecting filter results.

Comment: findBy(['selectOption' => true, 'LOCTYPE' => 9]) a small change i want to perform LOCTYPE not equal to 9, in that case how can i write.?

Comment: See the link to the other question I added in my answer.