# Symfony (php) comparison in FindBy statement

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony and need to compare to variables from my database called `$voorraad` and `$minimumvoorraad`. I need to see the product when `$voorraad` is lower than `$minimumvoorraad`. Since I am using Symfony we use the PHP language. I've tried the `FindByVoorrad` and `FindOneBy` statements with no success, I only get the header from my twig but that's it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you perhaps share the code you have tried (both SQL and PHP)?

Comment: For the "lower than" comparison, you need some custom code. Best solution would probably be to use [a custom Repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) with a query builder (similar [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089458))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your Entity consists of whatever fields including 'voorraad' and 'minimumvoorraad', you should be able to get your database table's content via

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT e
    FROM AppBundle:Entity e
    WHERE e.voorraad < e.minimumvoorraad'
);

$products = $query->getResult();
```

**Edit:** the *e* in the query is a SQL-typical alias defined inline.

And then treat your $products variable as usual, where you can use all of your getters and setters.

After rendering and passing your products to the Twig view

```
return $this->render('view.html.twig', array(
    'products' => $products
));
```

you could then proceed to print the products, for example, in a table inside your Twig view:

```
<table>
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.voorraad }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.minimumvoorraad }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I still had some trouble at first because I thought the e you use in your Query had to be something that already existed in your code, turned out it can just be something random. Again, thanks!

Comment: Woops, I am sorry - the "e" is an alias assigned to the table when building the SQL-Query, which is default MySQL-Syntax I believe. Should've mentioned, but glad you worked it out on your own!